# Login form with sqlite in windows phone application, app launch settings

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, application-settings

I am working with login form with local database(sqlite). I cannot retrieve the username & password from the inserted values/registered values. 
If the user closes the app with out selecting logout, in the next app launch the same page should be displayed. If he selects logout before closing the app while he opens the app it should display login page(with the help of Applicationdata, local settings)

Comment: your question is too broad, make it specific and what you've tried by yourself till now.? post some code you've tried for it.

Answer (score 1):

for app launch settings you've asked about:

- you need to set kind of a flag in `IsolatedStorageSettings` in wp app.

  ```
      IsolatedStorageSettings iso = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
      iso.Add("flag", true);
  ```

i.e. if the user is logged in then set this flag to true as described above. and when user logs out then set it to false.

- now check every time when app launches whether the flag is true or false. from that point you can know whether user has logged out or not.

  ```
      if (iso.Contains("flag"))
      {
          // check the value and proceed accordingly.
      }
  ```
- and from that point, you can navigate user to specific page like login page or the other page.

hope that helps..

Comment: Isolated storage settings can be found in silverlight applications. I am working with simple blank app. With the help of Application data local settings how can I implement them.